# Why is the concept of transcendental numbers linked with rational coefficients? Why not real nor complex coefficients?

Tags: polynomials, transcendental-numbers

I've read this:

> In mathematics, a transcendental number is a (possibly complex) number
>   that is not algebraic—that is, it is not a root of a non-zero
>   polynomial equation with rational coefficients.

Why does the concept of transcendental numbers was appended to polynomials with rational coefficients? Why not polynomials with real or complex coefficients? By the few mathematical readings I have done, I felt that it's not *safe* to work with reals or complex numbers in some mathematical concepts, I speculate that this *safety* (in the case of the transcendental numbers) can only be granted with rational numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An algebraic number can equivalently be defined as a root of a polynomial whose coefficients are all integers. So, the algebraic numbers are closely related to the integers, certainly an interesting class of objects to study.

When extending past the rational numbers, it is very natural to look at those numbers that occur as such roots before looking at the reals (at least from an algebraic point of view). The reason is that the reals require an analytic extension of the rationals, while the algebraic numbers are algebraic (i.e., not analytic).

Lastly, it makes no sense to wonder about reals or complex numbers that are roots of polynomials with real or complex coefficients: every real numbers (resp. complex number) is the root of a linear polynomial with real (resp. complex) coefficients.

Comment: What is the problem with the analytic extension of the rationals?

Comment: there is no problem with it. It's just a different sort of extension. A non-algebraic one.

Comment: The complex numbers are a transcendental extension of the algebraic numbers.

Answer (score 13):

Any real number $a$ is the solution of a polynomial equation with real coefficients:
$$
x-a=0.
$$

Comment: Furthermore, every complex number is also a solution of a polynomial (in fact at worst quadratic) equation with real coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

$x-\pi=0$ is a binomial equation with real coefficients.

See here for a proof that  is transcendental.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Answer (score 1):

A number is transcendental relative to a set from which to draw coefficients. If your coefficients are all complex numbers, there are no transcendental numbers. $\pi$ and $e$ are transcendental relative to the rationals, but not the reals.

If the base set is not mentioned, it's implied the number in question is transcendental relative to the rationals. Makes sense as a default since what's algebraic over the rationals is algebraic over the integers. It's not until you can prove a number can't be  the root of a rational polynomial that you establish a basis for the distinction.